# ANT+ bicycle shifting bypass

Tags: ant

I have electronic shifting on bike and I want to bypass it with my computer. So now, the network topology is:

controller <--> derailleur

and I want it to be:

controller --> PC with ANT+ usb dongle <--> derailleur.

Can someone give me hint on this please?

Comment: why do you think that this vague question is about IoT?

Comment: you cannot expect a hint if you do not say where you are stuck

Comment: What’s on the other end of the ANT+ link? Or are you missing a second ANT+ equipped device in your diagram? Also without any information about the controller or  dérailleur it’s going to be extremely difficult to guess what the interface between the two might be.

Comment: @jsotola ANT+ is widely used in embedded apps, co I thought it is relevant. But if you know some comunity where it would be more relevant, please let me know.

Comment: @jcaron I have derailleur, remote control ( both Sram axs) and PC with ant+ stick. All devices in diagram are present.

Comment: It would have been quite relevant to include in your question the fact the communication between controller and dérailleur is actually wireless… Also, what is it you want to do? Just listen to the commands being sent, or actually intercept them and modify/replace them?

Comment: It appears that the question has been abandoned by the questioner !  Perhaps the question should be closed.